# how to replace % in url with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, replace

i got one small issue, i need to replace all character expect letter and numbers in the URL with Htaccess

example

> > mp3/Nicholas-Tremulis-(ASCAP)-100%--Heartache.../

i want

> > mp3/Nicholas-Tremulis-ASCAP-100-Heartache/

i got more 400 error in webmaster

> > RewriteRule ^search/node/(.*)$ custom-search&searchterms=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: `need to replace all character expect letter and numbers` What about `- OR / OR ( OR )` in your URI?

Comment: except (- , /) or we can remove only % and &

Comment: But there is no `&` present in your example URI as shown.

Comment: okay, can you show me only for %, how to replac % from url

Comment: Presence of `%` makes your URL invalid from W3C standards. You must use `/mp3/Nicholas-Tremulis-(ASCAP)-100%25--Heartache`

Comment: ohh, okay how to use it

Comment: This might have negative sideeffects because `%` is a char used in url encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this recursive rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# executes when there are more than 1 % in URI
RewriteRule "^([^%]*)%+([^%]*%.*)$" $1$2 [N,NE]

# executes when there is exactly 1 % in URI    
RewriteRule "^([^%]*)%([^%]*)$" $1$2 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: i tried but it is not working,, getting same 400 error

Comment: You forgot what I mentioned in comments. You need to enter URI as `/mp3/Nicholas-Tremulis-(ASCAP)-100%25--Heartache`